# Views and Panels Newbie... Maybe simple...Hope its simple

Tags: views, panels

I have a simple view that does not page. It contains about 50 records (three fields each). When I import the view into column one of the panel page, it displays the entire contents. I wish to equally divide the content into the two columns.

I have done this before in PHP. I have the code to do this in PHP. But this is D, so,...

I tried to mock up the effect, to get a look at the output, by placing the same view in the second column. But Panels apparently did not do another query. The second column was blank.

Any ideas why the view would not copy into the second column, or how I might achieve my goal to divide the query into two columns using Views and Panels the Drupal way?

Answer (score 1):

I think you would not need panels for two column.

There are two ways I know:

1. Quick way: You can choose a styling format as grid and define columns as 2
2. Long way: A View listing can be shown in two columns by styling and template overriding.

Comment: I would guess 1 would allow me to split the content evenly. Although when I originally solved this in PHP the most frequent solution was horizontal and not vertical (lets say I had six records, 1,2,3,4,5,6. They can be ordered 1,2;3,4;5,6 or 1,4;2,5;3,6. And I need the latter solution. On 2 all I can say is during my learning of D, I've continually battled with wanting to do it my way in code or TDW:) Template overriding blurs the bounds. And if I overrode the template, I'd want the bells and whistles of my original solution, and I'm forcing myself to this conforming to TDW. (^_^)

Comment: And, ok, you caught me. I tried to ask my question in general terms, and that didn't get the goal across. My original was actually four columns and I added the ability to change the number of items in each column to even out at the bottom, because some records were one line and other were 9-12 lines. The record count() split was yucky. Whatever I decide, the goal is to see how close I can get using just Panels and Views.

Comment: Can you try Alignment settings just below the Number of Columns. 
- Horizontal: Horizontal alignment will place items starting in the upper left and moving right.
- Vertical: Vertical alignment will place items starting in the upper left and moving down.